# Excel IF statement setting a fix value

Tags: excel

I just want to know the right syntax for this IF statement.

I just want to set a specific value to a cell.

My syntax is:

=IF(HOUR(F2)>6,F2=6)

Correct me if I miss something.

Comment: You cannot change the value of another cell using a formula. i.e. if you are testing the value of F2, you cannot change it with a formula in another cell. Do you perhaps have a formula in F2? You could change *that* formula.

Comment: Here is the scenario,

Comment: Whenever i put a value, example i put 9 in the F2, can i stricly change it by 6? Whenever higher than 6 is put there

Comment: You mean that you are manually putting `9` in F2? If so, I can find two solutions: 1. Using Data Validation to prompt the user to enter a value 6 or below (and reject the current value), 2. Writing a VBA script (macro) to automatically handle such events. Do you have a preference?

Comment: Sorry Im not a excel expert so I dont have ideas for macro, as for your question, yes I manually putting a value in the F2 cell,

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps use the Data Validation feature of Excel. For example, in the below scenario, I'm putting this data validation on cell B2. So I select it first and go to Data > Data Validation:

[image]

Then I pick some options:

[image]

A user will be able to enter only a value between 0 and 6 inclusive.

---

A macro that could do that would be:

To use this macro, right click on the sheet tab and click on 'View Code'. Copy and paste the below, run (play button) and save.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$F$2" Then
        If Target.Value > TimeValue("06:00") Then
            Target.Value = TimeValue("06:00")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Whenever a time above 6:00 am will be entered, the macro will automatically change it to 6:00 am. Formatting of the cell may be required.

Comment: Example I put 7:00am there, can I set a value of 6(6:00am)

Comment: @Kevin If you change the 'Allow' to 'Time' and change the minimum and maximum accordingly, then you will have to type in `6:00am` for it to work. Putting 7:00 am will give you a warning.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but If posssible, is there a way to just simply change the value of someone input greater than 6am,                              Its like this                                                               If (F2 >= 6){                                                                  F2 = 6;

Comment: @Kevin That will require a macro. I could try to look for one (I too am not used to Macros :s).

Comment: @Kevin I added a macro solution to my answer.

Comment: Maybe this is too much, but can you teach how to input that?because I try to put that in macro but no luck on my side.

Comment: @Kevin Hmm, could you try reading this: [link](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/events.html) (under heading "Worksheet Change Event")? At step 3, copy paste the above code there. I'm not sure if you need to enable the 'Developer' tab first and if you do, then go to File > Options > Customize Ribbon > Check 'Developer' tab

Comment: I done with the code, how can I implement it to a specific cell?

Comment: @Kevin You see the line `Target.Address = "$F$2"` Here, the specific cell F2 is affected by the macro. Change as required! Hmm, for ranges, I will have to look and confirm but I don't think it should be too hard.